# Pandas adding sub columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
Id  Day  Name Value1  Value2  Value3 ... Value10 factor  
11    1   x    1        2       3    ...     10    2
11    1   y    10       9       8    ...     1     2
11    1   z    2        2       2    ...     2     2
22    2   i    3        3       4    ...     4     3
22    2   j    0        0       1    ...     1     3
```

My goal is to sum the values in the "Value" columns and multiply it by its factor.  The output would be:

```
Id  Day  Value1     Value2    Value3 ... Value10 
11    1  2*(1+10+2) 2*(2+0+2) 2*(3+8+2)  2*(10+1+2)  
22    2  3*(3+0)    3*(3+0)   3*(4+1)    3*(4+1)
```

My approach is to group them by ID but then I don't want to add the "Day", and I'm not sure what would be the right way to handle this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for columns for later aggregating `sum`
- [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) columns with `Value` in columns name and multiple by column `factor`
- aggregate [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) by both levels of MultiIndex
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

---

```
df = df.set_index(['Id','Day'])
df = df.filter(like='Value').mul(df['factor'], axis=0).sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index()
print (df)
   Id  Day  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value10
0  11    1      26      26      26       26
1  22    2       9       9      15       15
```

Similar solution for get all columns for multiple by [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) with `list`:

```
df = df.set_index(['Id','Day'])
cols = df.columns.difference(['factor', 'Name'])
df = df[cols].mul(df['factor'], axis=0).sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index()
print (df)
   Id  Day  Value1  Value10  Value2  Value3
0  11    1      26       26      26      26
1  22    2       9       15       9      15
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) what if the columns' name were just "1 2 3..." instead of "Value1 Value2..."?

Comment: Give me as sec.

Comment: @TylerNG: `filter` also accepts regular expressions (see the `regex` flag), so you can define precisely which columns to use (for example, that it should be a single digit).